# Can I purchase only one certificate and use it to sign/protect many resources?

Tags: ssl, windows-installer, code-signing, pfx, x509

I have done some research and I learned that both PFX files and SSL certificates are X.509 certificates. Then I wondered: can I purchase only one certificate (PFX/SSL/CER) and use it for many purposes? I need to do the following:

- Allow HTTPS/SSL on my website (very important)
- Sign PDF documents (very important)
- Sign EXE/MSI files (important)
- Sign e-mail messages (optional)

Do I need to purchase one certificate for each purpose? Or can I use only one certificate?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL certs and Code Signing certs are different animals and can't be used interchangeably.  One certifies a publisher and one certifies a fully qualified domain name.

Comment: Also I would add that secure email is different certificate as well.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe an alternative would be to create a certificate issued by my own CA, like that?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428335/make-your-own-certificate-for-signing-files/9685605#9685605

Comment: You can create your own certs but they won't be very useful if other people don't trust them.